# iBooks highlight style for buttons on website

Tags: javascript, css

I want to implement a special highlighting to by buttons. The one, I found on the iBooks app for iPhone/iPad suites my needs. I think it is very complex due to the fact that all the strokes are looking different. I could use some CSS-Sprites-Voodoo but I don’t think I will be able to assign these styles so easily. Has anyone done something similar? I would be happy to hear some ideas.

Thanks, Floyd

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SlfHx.png

Comment: I'm not too sure about what you are asking. Do you want to highlight text on a webpage? Do you want to make a button highlight on rollover? Please clarify, and show us some code/images to explain what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried this out: http://jsfiddle.net/brianflanagan/XUpFc/  Basically, the gist is to grab any selected text and wrap it in a span to give it a class with a background image.  Not sure how useful this is, but it might get you started...